# What is the Latin for good/ bad vibes?

Tags: english-to-latin-translation, translation-check

Clearly this word ‘vibes’ is colloquial, if not slang. My first attempts were to modify a phrase from Plautus for ‘good vibes’ viz. ab initio inter nos congrūimus concorditer and from Cicero for ‘bad vibes’ ab initio inter nos erat quoddam odium quasi naturale. Is the latter perhaps too literary? But I am sure there are better suggestions from colleagues.

Comment: As with all translation, the context matters; I can think of 'good vibes' being used to describe a coffee shop, a bar, an album of music, a person, a party, a novel, a film and more, and while the connotations overlap the meaning isn't the same. I also suspect that what I (a British adult) understand by 'good vibes' is probably different to what an American teenager might, with subtle distinctions I'm not cool enough to get.

Comment: I am also a British adult and, I think that ‘good vibes’ or indeed ‘bad vibes’ in the sense you pertinently cite might be something straightforward as, e.g. bonos (or ‘malos’ ) mihi parit/excitat sensus hic locus’. – 
Jonathan Hadfield
 15 hours ago    Delete